# Automatically re-indexing Sunspot/Solr on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am using [Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) wich is a [Solr-based search engine](https://sunspot.github.io/) on my rails app.

According to [this Rails Cast episode on `Search with Sunspot`:](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot?view=asciicast)

> Sunspot automatically indexes any new records but not existing ones. We can tell Sunspot to reindex the existing records by running: `rake sunspot:reindex`

Which should basically reindex the whole Model.

However, I have a Model (`TicketSubject`), with an attribute, `category`, and I will like to reindex a `ticket_subject` each time there is an edit on its `category`.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an ActiveRecord callback for this i.e. `after_update`?

**after_update()**
Is called after Base.save on existing objects that have a record. Note that this callback is still wrapped in the transaction around save. For example, if you invoke an external indexer at this point it won‘t see the changes in the database.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M001377

Define: **Callbacks** are hooks into the life cycle of an Active Record object that allow you to *trigger logic before or after an alteration* of the object state. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was thinking in that line as well, however, what is the `sunspost` command that will be run to re-index only the particular object that has changed and not the whole record?

Comment: The object is the record. Say, when the category attribute of a TicketSubject is edited and saved the corresponding record has to be updated in the DB as well. So you can't avoid the case of the record not being wholly updated. I'm not talking about the whole table just that particular record

Comment: Yeah :-). We are saying the same thing here... just different options of wordings. What is the `sunspot` command to re-index only this record (only this object, `only this ticket_subject`) as opposed to re-indexing the whole table?

Comment: [Think I found it though...](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#reindexing-objects) Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! I hope it all goes well